# How to access Dropbox API via Oauth?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I have about a site with about 50 customers. They each have a user profile. They want to be able to automatically include their images *which they store on DropBox* in their profiles.

My idea is to make a Dropbox api that scans their folders (with their permission) and just include the images in their profile. I already know how to link directly to their images as long as I have the url.

I set up the Ruby API. Only question is : Do they have to authorize my app *every time* I try to access their images?

I want to somehow store authorization information for each client, then just reuse that info and access their images through the Ruby API. Is this possible? How is it done?

I think if I can just get past this authorization hurdle I can take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this. Just store the access token at the end of the OAuth flow and reuse it. From https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ruby:

> The access token is all you'll need to make API requests on behalf of
>   this user, so you should store it away for safe-keeping (even though
>   we don't for this tutorial). By storing the access token, you won't
>   need to go through these steps again unless the user reinstalls your
>   app or revokes access via the Dropbox website.